# Symfony2 /FOS call to undefined method on the user model

Tags: inheritance, symfony, fosuserbundle

This is the error message I get when, for example, I go to the register url:

```
**Call to undefined method MyEntity::setEnabled() FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController.php on line 44**
```

(FOS is registered in my kernel)

my own user entity extends *FOS\UserBundle\Model\User* and I've also tried to extend *FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User*

As this:

```
<?php

namespace NRtworks\SubscriptionBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="icousers")
 */
class icousers extends BaseUser
{

        /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique = true)
     */

    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=5)
     */

    protected $customer;

       public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function getid()
    {
        return $this->id;
    } 

    public function gettype()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }          
    public function getcustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }        

    public function setid($x)
    {
        return $this->id=$x;
    } 
    public function settype($x)
    {
        return $this->type=$x;
    } 
     public function setcustomer($x)
    {
        return $this->customer=$x;
    } 
}

?>
```

I did not change the code so the method setEnabled is written into *FOS\UserBundle\Model\User*

I have no idea what's wrong here...

I use Symfony 2.1.7

Comment: Your icousers must extend UserBundle\Entity\User.  Follow the instruction in the readme files.  Not sure where your error message is coming from.  Start by verifying the $user class returned from $userManager->getUser.  Pretty sure it won't be an instance of icousers.

Comment: thank for your answer. I've found my mistake, it was a stupid one (not related to the bundle technic).